# How to add wxWidgets to project via cmake?

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

So I am using clion, trying to build a project with wxwidgets. But I get this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2020.1/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS core)
```

Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(BedrockFinderCpp)

set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR <c:/Program Files/wxWidgets-3.1.4>)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS core)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    BFFApp.cpp
    BFFGui.cpp
    PrecomputedRandAdvance.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Do you **literally** write angle brackets in the path `<c:/Program Files/wxWidgets-3.1.4>`? Or what do these brackets mean?

Comment: @E1ZY, well you don't have this option in your "cmake" settings. Can you add it and check? There are multiple references about "cmake" and wxwidgets n the web.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah this was kinda dumb but it didn't work neither without them nor with " "

Comment: @Igor I am a bit confused how can I add it to settings?

Answer (score 0):

I found a "fix" by myself. It can be done with this code:

NOTE: wxWidgets is a subdirectory that contains files from the wxWidgets-3.1.4 directory

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(BedrockFinderCpp)

add_subdirectory(wxWidgets)

find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    BFFApp.cpp
    BFFGui.cpp
    PrecomputedRandAdvance.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} wx::core ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Do you places **sources** of wxWidgets under `C:/Program Files`? Oh, no, do not do that: `C:/Program Files` is for **installed** programs which are already **built**. And, assuming `C:/Program Files/wxWidgets-3.1.4` to contain **sources**, `find_package(wxWidgets)` definitely wont work for them. `find_package` requires corresponded project to be already **built** and **installed**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so I should build wxWidgets with cmake before I build my project?

Comment: You should **build** and **install** wxWidgets before building you project. Only in that case `find_package(wxWidgets)` will work. Building wxWidgets alongside with your project, as you do with `add_subdirectory(wxWidgets)`, could also work. But note that this approach could not work for packages, other than wxWidgets.